# PIC18F blink led

Tags: microcontroller, pic, port

Hi I am trying to blink LED with 18f4550, and I am getting no success.

I have defined the PORTD as output , TRISD=0;

I am trying to blink led with Some delay of 50 ms on mplabx and xc8,

I don’t want to use the LATDbits to set the led to High. Instead I am trying

PORTD=0b00000000; format.

Sample

```
#include<pic18f4550>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 2000000

void main(void)
{
 TRISD=0; //output
    while(1)
      {
         PORTD = 0b10000000; // Dont want to use LATDbits.RD0=1;
         __delay_ms(50);
         PORTD = 0b01000000;
        __delay_ms(50);
   } 
}
```

If am using LATDbits.RD0=1; then its working fine the way its supposed to be. But I want to use PORTD =0b00000000; format because it is little convenient . Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You write to LAT and read from PORT. What is wrong with using LATDbits.RD0=1? If you really don't want to use it, substitute LATD for PORTD, but I'll be if you look at the disassembly, it will be identical.

Comment: If you are using RD0 for the LED, the order of your PORTD bit assignments is reversed. Change to PORTD = 0b00000001; etc.

Comment: Thank you tut, It just didnt come to my mind :D .. yes the bit assignment got reversed. thanks man :) Problem Solved. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RD0 for the LED, the order of your PORTD bit assignments is reversed. Change to PORTD = 0b00000001; etc.

As Matt mentioned, the use of LATD is preferred for outputs.

Comment: thanks :) , Got one more doubt , is it the same for PIC18F2550 also ? I wish to blink RB0 and RB1 in PortB of 18f2550 then it should be PORTD=0b11000000;  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Binary notation is independent of the processor, although it may be compiler dependent as I don't think it is a part of the C standards (I could be wrong). That said, the least-significant bit is on the right and the most-significant bit is on the left. I have never seen it otherwise. Your comment is incorrect in two ways (wrong port and wrong bit order). It should be something like PORTB=0b00000011; if you wish to set RB0 and RB1.

Comment: ... Even better: LATB |= 0b00000011; and then after the delay: LATB &= 0bffffff00; ... This will toggle RB0 and RB1 without affecting the other bits in PORTB.

Comment: Oh lord... yes u are right, I was actually about to say same... that, if i want RB0 then should it be  PORTB=0b00000011 . I am sooo sorry. Dont know what i was thinking... Thanks for helping me out. :D :D Alright i would go with LATB